# sqlite3 update table value doesn't update timestamp

Tags: sqlite, sql-update, unix-timestamp

i'm using SQLite3 and i have a very simple table:

```sql
create table pulseCount (
  pulses INTEGER NOT NULL,
  timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT (1000*(strftime('%s','now')+mod(strftime('%f','now'),1)))
);
```

problem is, when i update the `pulses` value, the timestamp doesn't update as well.  i read that i need a trigger to do this, but i wasn't able to make head or tails of the discussion and resolve it to something concrete or useful.  and, yes, i do need to be keeping track down to the millisecond.

should be noted that, as far as i can tell, the timestamp updates on `INSERT`, but not on `UPDATE`, which is what is needed.

anyone willing to lend a hand here?

EDIT:
as requested, the `UPDATE` command:

```sql
UPDATE pulseCount SET pulses=1;
```

as there's only one row, there's no need for a `WHERE` clause.

EDIT:

well, i managed to bash together a trigger that seems to work just fine:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [UpdateTimestamp]
  AFTER UPDATE ON pulseCount
  WHEN old.pulses <> new.pulses
BEGIN
  UPDATE pulseCount 
    SET timestamp = (1000*(strftime('%s','now')+mod(strftime('%f','now'),1)))
    WHERE pulses >= 0;
END
```

if anyone sees a problem with this, please do let me know.  i don't know that the final `WHERE` clause is needed, but it can't hurt... although if it can save me a few milliseconds, i'd like to know.

Comment: You need to show the actual code that executes the `UPDATE` command, for anyone to figure out what may be wrong.

Comment: shouldn't really matter, it's an UPDATE; but TBF, it should be there for completion sake.

Comment: You are updating the `pulseCount` but not the `timestamp`. You need to update both.

Comment: And here is the official detail from the SQLiite documentation: *The DEFAULT clause specifies a default value to use for the column if no value is explicitly provided by the user when doing an **INSERT**.*

Comment: @OldBoy   you are correct; i just didn't read that far.  i'm coming from a MySQL background where this is just automatic, for the most part.  plus, i have mgmt breathing down my neck today.  i love coding for the uneducated...